# Push notification in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-notification

I am working on a attendance registration system where a user of an office can make a leave request. When any user makes a leave request, it must be notified to admin. How do I implement it ?

I had seen django-fcm for push notification. But I am using django rest framework . Can I implement django-fcm with django rest ?

If any tutorials link would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very hard, clone the fcm-django-web-demo project and try coding in Django shell...